# Binding with for grid Column

Tags: vb.net, binding, grid, width

I have a grid with 3 columns. I want that when you click on a button, the first column changes width.

This is the code, but doesn't work. Why?

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width= "{Binding Path=PositionCol,Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="column1"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>

    <Button Content="Button" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="4,4,4,4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55" Click="Button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Window1

    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private _PositionCol As Double
    Public Property PositionCol As Double
        Get
            Return _PositionCol
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            _PositionCol = value
            OnPropertyChanged("PositionCol")
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        PositionCol = 70
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that [`ColumnDefinition.Width`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.columndefinition.width%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is typed as [`GridLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridlength(v=vs.110).aspx), not `Double`.  Change your property:

```
Private _PositionCol As GridLength = New GridLength(200)
Public Property PositionCol As GridLength
    Get
        Return _PositionCol
    End Get
    Set(value As GridLength)
        _PositionCol = value
        OnMyPropertyChanged("PositionCol")
    End Set
End Property

' ...

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
    PositionCol = New GridLength(70)
End Sub
```

Also, make sure you are setting the `DataContext` in the constructor:

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    Me.DataContext = Me

End Sub
```

You'll probably want to tweak the column definitions some, too:

```xml
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding Path=PositionCol,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2"/>
    <ColumnDefinition/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```